# C++ reversing a string with only one string

Tags: c++

I am trying to reversing a string with only using one string, but when I output the string it is missing a letter. Is something being over written that I do not know about? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {
  string d = "jakejosh"; //11 
  char temp = '\0';
  int j = d.size()/2;
  for (int i=d.size()/2; i> 0; i--) //5
  {
    temp = d[i+j];
    d[j+i] = d[j-i];
    d[j-i] = temp;
  }

  cout << d << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output is: `ttam olle`

Output should be: `ttam olleh`

Comment: Step through in a debugger. Watch what happens to `d` each time the loop body is done. Or add an output statement there.

Comment: You're mixing `char` and `string` types. Look [here](http://stjarnhimlen.se/snippets/strrev.c) for a solution using `char`.

Comment: @ForceBru And in which ways does this really matter?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, to my mind, as C++ has it's own type for string/characters, it can be better to use it without any C stuff. Just not to mess C and C++.

Comment: I think it would be less messy if you iterated in the opposite direction (begin to middle).

Answer (score 3):

When the size of a string is even then the code is wrong. For example if the size is equal to 2 then size() / 2 is equal to 1 and in the loop you will get thet d[i+j] is equivalent to d[size() / 2 + size() / 2] that is equal to d[2] while the valid range of indices is [0,1]
Also you should include header `<string>` and you could use standard function `std::swap`

The simplest approach is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "hello matt";

    s = std::string( s.rbegin(), s.rend() );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to write the loop yourself then the code can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "hello matt";

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size() / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[s.size()-i-1];
        s[s.size()-i-1] = s[i];
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can write some exotic solution.:) For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    std:: string s = "Jake Smith"; 

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0, j = s.size(); j - i > 1; i++  )
    {
        std::swap( s[i], s[--j] );
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Jake Smith
htimS ekaJ
```

Or you can try to write a recursive function.

At last you could use standard algorithm `std::reverse` declared in header `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::reverse() to do that. For educational purposes take a look at the following pure C algorithms: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-reverse-string

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=d.size()/2; i> 0; i--) //5
  {

    temp = d[i+j-1]; // d[9] i.e.must be 9 not 10 for swapping with 'h'
    d[j+i-1] = d[j-i];
    d[j-i] = temp;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to trip up with indices when reversing a string in place.

If your string is of length `LEN`, then the valid indices are `0` - `N-1`.

In your case, let's take a look at the middle and how you start swapping from there.

```
hello matt
```

For reversing the string, you'll have to swap

```
hello matt (swap 0-th and 9-th)
^        ^
hello matt (swap 1-st and 8-th)
 ^      ^
hello matt (swap 2-nd and 7-th)
  ^    ^
hello matt (swap 3-rd and 6-th)
   ^  ^
hello matt (swap 4-th and 5-th)
    ^^
```

The start value for `i` is `(N-1)/2`.

The end vale for `i` is `0`.

The index for swapping the value at `i` is `len - 1 - i`. (swap `d[0]` with `d[9]` in your case)

Putting that all together, the function should be something like:

```
void reverse_string(string& d)
{
   int len = d.length();
   for (int i=(len-1)/2; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      int j = len - 1 - i;
      char temp = d[j];
      d[j] = d[i];
      d[i] = temp;
   }
}
```

Here's the `main` function to test it.

```
int main()
{
   string d = "hello matt"; 
   reverse_string(d);
   cout << d << endl;

   d = "hello max"; 
   reverse_string(d);
   cout << d << endl;

   return 0;
}
```